# Batch script Mix Forfiles Cmd to print a PDF

Tags: batch-file, printing, forfiles

I'm stuck with this script

```
echo off
SET pathAdobe="C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"
SET pathDestination=T:\
cd %pathDestination%

(1)
forfiles /P %pathDestination% /M *8.pdf /D +0 /C "cmd /c echo @PATH"
(2)
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /o /h /s /t "%pathDestination%\pdf8.pdf" "MyPrinterName"


pause
```

(1) Work fine, i got a list of pdf according my forfiles

(2) Work fine, print my file

(3) But when i want to mix the 2 first step that doesn't work like i want

```
forfiles /P %pathDestination% /M *8.pdf /D +0 /C "CMD /C "%pathAdobe%" /o /h /s /t @PATH"
```

I got this error:
Error: Invalid argument or option - « Files\Adobe\Acrobat »

I try to escape with ^ " \ but don't change the result

Can't find a solution!

Thanks for any help you can give me :)

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are including double quotes, in the wrong places, and that those double quotes require escaping. You can escape those using backward slashes *(`\"`)*, or by using their hexadecimal character code, *(`0x22`)*.

Backward slash example:

```sh
@Echo Off
Set "pathAdobe=%ProgramFiles%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"
Set "pathDestination=T:\"
CD /D "%pathDestination%" 2> NUL || Exit /B
%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /M "*8.pdf" /D 0 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"\"%pathAdobe%\" /o /h /s /t @Path \"MyPrinterName\"\""
Pause
```

Hexadecimal character example:

```sh
@Echo Off
Set "pathAdobe=%ProgramFiles%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"
Set "pathDestination=T:\"
CD /D "%pathDestination%" 2> NUL || Exit /B
%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /M "*8.pdf" /D 0 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C 0x220x22%pathAdobe%0x22 /o /h /s /t @Path 0x22MyPrinterName0x220x22"
Pause
```

Comment: It works much better indeed, thanks for the help @Compo 

It is not yet optimal because between two prints I have to close Adobe Acrobate manually
If you know how to solve this i will appreciate a lot :)

Comment: Take a look at the content of `taskkill /?` within a Command Prompt window, (`%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe`). _You could optionally look at the content from `tasklist /?` too_

Comment: Sorry to start this topic again, I didn't take the time to work on it before.
I managed to make taskkill work independently without any problem but I can't use it in the forfiles

I made multiple try

This one wait i close Adobe before made the taskkill so it's useless
<pre>
%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P %pathDestination% /M "*88.pdf" /D 0 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe %SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /im Acrobat.exe /f & %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"\"%pathAdobe%\" /o /h /s /t @Path \"HP Informatique\"\""
</pre>

Comment: And this one do the same, he don't launch the taskkill commande before i close Adobe
<pre>
%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P %pathDestination% /M "*88.pdf" /D 0 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"\"%pathAdobe%\" /o /h /s /t @Path \"HP Informatique\"\" & %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe %SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /im Acrobat.exe /f"
<pre>

Comment: @Julien, you appear to be trying to force close Adobe, at the end, not after each iteration. Not only should you not be using the `/F` option, but I'm not here to provide support under this question, beyond that which was initially asked and answered.